# why can't multiple clients be connected to a server in the same time? Python

Tags: python-3.x, sockets

So lets say I have a server.py and a client.py with the following code:

server.py

```
import socket

def listen():
    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    host = "127.0.0.1"
    port = 5555

    s.bind((host, port))
    s.listen(128)

    print("LISTENING FOR INCOMING CONNECTIONS")

    c, addr = s.accept()
    print("GOT CONNECTION FROM", addr)

    while True:
        data = c.recv(1024)
        data = data.decode("utf-8")
        data = data.upper()
        c.send(data.encode("utf-8"))
listen()
```

and client.py

```
import socket

def connect():
    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    host = "127.0.0.1"
    port = 5555

    s.connect((host, port))

    print("CONNECTED TO HOST")

    while True:
        command = input("command> ")
        s.send(command.encode("utf-8"))
        data = s.recv(1024)
        print(str(data.decode("utf-8")))
connect()
```

And now if I disconnect the client and try to reconnect to the server it won't work. (and by will not work I mean the connection won't get established)

Answer (score 1):

In your `listen` function in `server.py`, you are only calling the `accept` function once. `accept` must be called for each client connection you want to accept. To resolve your problem, you can just put the latter part of the function in a loop:

```
def listen():
    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    host = "127.0.0.1"
    port = 5555

    s.bind((host, port))
    s.listen(128)

    while True:
        print("Waiting for an incoming connection...")
        c, addr = s.accept()
        print("GOT CONNECTION FROM", addr)

        # Serve the connection
        try:
            while True:
                data = c.recv(1024)
                if len(data) == 0:
                    print("Client closed connection")
                    break
                data = data.decode("utf-8")
                data = data.upper()
                c.send(data.encode("utf-8"))
        except Exception as e:
            print("Connection died: {}".format(e))
```

This *will* mean that only 1 client can be connected at a time.

Instead of writing this type of code yourself, I'd highly recommend taking a look at SocketServer in the Python standard library. This library takes care of the boilerplate listen/accept stuff and also has some advanced features that lets you easily handle more than one client connection at the same time (if you need that)

https://docs.python.org/3/library/socketserver.html#socketserver-tcpserver-example

Comment: Thank you I will take a look at the docs and see what I can do to fix it.